# Opensource API for reading IFC Files in Java

Tags: java, ifc

Can someone please suggest me an opensource API (SDK) for reading IFC file ? I need to acces at the file content.

Answer (score 1):

[JSDAI](http://www.jsdai.net/) can handle EXPRESS and STEP files. You can use it to parse for example the [IFC 4x1 schema](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/review/IFC4x1/rc3/IFC4x1_RC3.exp) and read EXPRESS files. On the JSDAI website, there are also some small videos that show how to use it in conjunction with Eclipse.

Not Open Source, but Java related:
[IFC TOOLS PROJECT](http://www.ifctoolsproject.com/)

You can also write your own early binding to be able to read/write STEP files (e.g. [oipExpress](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/oipExpress) which is C++ related but could be extended to support Java)